# Ruby robotic control

Tags: ruby, robotics

How would a person use Ruby to control a robot or some other robotic device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) is becoming popular for creating electronic devices that can be controlled by computers. It seems you can use a gem called `serialport` (http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/ruby) to control it in Ruby.

Comment: Hey thanks man that's seems to look pretty great. And I believe that that's what I was looking for!